# addEventListener(load) Error Assigning load eventListener to an id on another page

Tags: javascript

(javascript, no jquery)
Hello,

I am recieving the following error. "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null". I have one javascript file that is being used by two pages. One of the pages has a "load" eventListener attached to it. However, everytime I open the intitial page I get an error that states "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null".

I am going to assume that the reason I get this error is because the id (provisioningPages) is not on the current page. How do I assign the "load" event listener to an id outside of the current page?

So basically this:

2 html pages share 1 javascript file

page 1 = no load function

page 2 = has a load function

Every time i open page 1 it throws the above mentioned error. How do I assign the addEventListener to the id on Page 2 without it firing when opening page 1.

This is the code I am currently using
.`document.getElementById("provisioningPages").addEventListener("load", loadStoredInforamtionOnToPage());`

It seems that upon opening page 1 it looks for "provisioningPages" and since it cannot find it it throws the error. How do I prevent that?

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the error, you can simply check if the element exists in DOM.

```
var elem = document.getElementById("provisioningPages");
if (elem != null) {
    elem.addEventListener("load", loadStoredInforamtionOnToPage());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. It was that simple. Lol. Appreciate it.